# Is there anything that can only be accomplished by legacy indexes in Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j

I'm assuming the best practice for Neo4j (using v2.2.3 and higher) is to use `MATCH` with the new indexing and avoid using `START` and legacy indexes--which I don't think you can even create with Cypher.

Is there any current functionality that cannot be adequately achived  using 100% new methods and avoiding legacy indexes entirely?

Comment: I wrote about it here: http://jexp.de/blog/2015/04/on-neo4j-indexes-match-merge/

Comment: @MichaelHunger oh, you work there.  Guess your answers will tend to be correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the documentation, [full-text and Lucene indexes are considered legacy indexes](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-create-advanced.html).

So I think the answer to your question is, "Yes, quite a lot".

For example, [anything you'd do via the lucene syntax](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-lucene-extras.html) would probably fall into that category.   Fuzzy search, edit distance search, querying for numeric ranges, etc.

New schema indexes and methods that have come along since 2.0 I don't think address those features in any way.

**EDIT**  See also a [related answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256461/how-lucene-works-with-neo4j/26257279#26257279) about how lucene indexes work.

Comment: I'm starting to see a lot of simple things aren't easily accomplished by the new 'schema' indexing--even basic indexes on relationship properties.

Comment: There is a `LIKE` clause coming in next Cypher version for fulltext search. However I would love to know your use case for indexed relationship properties

Comment: I think it's important to keep in mind that neo4j 2.0 isn't that old; any notion of "schema" in neo4j is a very recent development.  You're not wrong, but the database is moving pretty fast right now.  They've been pretty good about taking comments and feature requests; I think in general the dev community would be interested to hear about problems/pain that is caused by this or that index being missing.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits do you know the cypher syntax to create legacy indexes on relationships?  is there such an animal?

Comment: No such thing - you can't create legacy indexes via Cypher AFAIK.  It's something that you do via java, or via config file hacking, or via REST API http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-indexes.html#rest-api-create-node-index

Comment: But in general, I'd be a big fan of "anything that is possible in the DB ought to be possible via cypher".